# Old unlicensed Office 2016 copy shows as licensed - Office 365 shows as unlicensed

Tags: office365

My system had an unlicensed copy of Professional 2016 on it.
I have now purchased an Office 365 Business, but I am unable to delete the Professional 2016 version (which seems to be the installed version).
Also, my Office 365 shows as View Only (Unlicesed).

Comment: What have you tried? What is your system? What is your question? Please edit your question to make it clear. Thanks.

Comment: An Office 365 installation is an Office 2016/2019 installation.  The only difference is that if you log into your Microsoft Account that has an active subscription you get monthly updates to Office.  You have logged into your account with the subscription right?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you Office license was consumed by Office 2016 instead of Office 365.

I would suggest to uninstall Office 2016 as described in the Microsoft article
[Uninstall Office from a PC](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).
Be carefull to uninstall Office 2016 and not Office 365.

The article also describes a Fix tool that completely wipes out Office.
There is the problem that it might also wipe out Office 365,
so if you find yourself needing to use it, then uninstall Office 365 first
as described in the article.

There is also a Microsoft Technet script for PowerShell,
[Uninstall Office 2016](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Uninstall-Office-2016-6f3fa204),
which can also help uninstall and clean up. It is also supposed to wipe all Office
versions of all types.

After Office 2016 is wiped out and only Office 365 is installed, try to activate
again. In the case that Office 365 will refuse, saying that the key has already
been used, you will need to call Microsoft Support to clean up the mess.